# Avoid useless subqueries or aggregations when joining and grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have two tables, `room` and `message`, in a chat database :

```
CREATE TABLE room (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    private boolean NOT NULL default false,
    description text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE message (
    id bigserial primary key,
    room integer references room(id),
    author integer references player(id),
    created integer NOT NULL,
);
```

Let's say I want to get the rooms with the numbers of messages from an user and dates of most recent message :

```
 id | number | last_created | description |      name        | private 
----+--------+--------------+-------------+------------------+---------
  2 |   1149 |   1391703964 |             | Dragons & co     | t
  8 |    136 |   1391699600 |             | Javascript       | f
 10 |     71 |   1391684998 |             | WBT              | t
  1 |     86 |   1391682712 |             | Miaou            | f
  3 |    423 |   1391681764 |             | Code & Baguettes | f
  ...
```

I see two solutions :

**1)** selecting/grouping on the messages and using subqueries to get the room columns :

```
select m.room as id, count(*) number, max(created) last_created,
(select name from room where room.id=m.room),
(select description from room where room.id=m.room),
(select private from room where room.id=m.room)
from message m where author=$1 group by room order by last_created desc limit 10
```

This makes 3 almost identical subqueries. This looks very dirty. I could reverse it to do only 2 suqueries on message columns but it wouln't be much better.

**2)** selecting on both tables and using aggregate functions for all columns :

```
select room.id, count(*) number, max(created) last_created,
max(name) as name, max(description) as description, bool_or(private) as private
from message, room
where message.room=room.id and author=$1
group by room.id order by last_created desc limit 10
```

All those aggregate functions look messy and useless.

Is there a clean solution here ?

It looks like a general problem to me. Theoretically, those aggregate functions are useless as, by construct, all the joined rows are the same row. I'd like to know if there's a general solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try performing the grouping in a subquery:

```
select m.id, m.number, m.last_created, r.name, r.description, r.private
from (
    select m.room as id, count(*) number, max(created) last_created
    from message m 
    where author=$1 
    group by room 
) m
 join room r
   on r.id = m.id
order by m.last_created desc limit 10
```

**Edit:** Another option (likely with similar performance) is to move that aggregation into a view, something like:

```
create view MessagesByRoom
as 
select m.author, m.room, count(*) number, max(created) last_created,
from message m 
group by author, room
```

And then use it like:

```
select m.room, m.number, m.last_created, r.name, r.description, r.private
from MessagesByRoom m
 join room r
   on r.id = m.room
where m.author = $1
order by m.last_created desc limit 10
```

Comment: How does it help? That adds yet **another** layer of complexity. Doesn't it?

Comment: @qwertynl It removes some aggregations, though

Comment: All you did was move the aggregations to a subquery. You have to create a temp table.

Comment: @qwertynl It's all up to the optimizer. I'm familiar with SQL Server, and definitely would expect this to be faster there.

Comment: @qwertynl maybe I don't know Postgres well enough, but in SQL Server that would definitely not make a temp table.

Comment: @dystroy Sorry, I messed up .room and .id

Comment: @JohnGibb There was another problem or two. I fixed that. It looks fast enough.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use a join?

```
SELECT 
  r.id, count(*) number_of_posts, 
  max(m.created) last_created,
  r.name, r.description, r.private
FROM room r
JOIN message m on r.id = m.room
WHERE m.author = $1
GROUP BY r.id 
ORDER BY last_created desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include the columns in the `group by`:

```
select room.id, count(*) number, max(message.created) last_created,
       room.name, room.description, room.private
from message join
     room
     on message.room=room.id and author=$1
group by room.id, name, description, private
order by last_created desc
limit 10;
```

EDIT:

This query will work in more recent versions of Postgres:

```
select room.id, count(*) number, max(message.created) last_created,
       room.name, room.description, room.private
from message join
     room
     on message.room=room.id and author=$1
group by room.id
order by last_created desc
limit 10;
```

Earlier versions of the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) are pretty clear that you would need to include all the columns:

> When GROUP BY is present, it is not valid for the SELECT list
>   expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate
>   functions, since there would be more than one possible value to return
>   for an ungrouped column.

The ANSI standard actually does allow the above query with just `group by room.id`.  This is a rather recent addition to the functionality of databases that support it.

Comment: I hadn't thought about that. That *might* be cleaner but it's still redundant and according to `explain analyze` it's much slower.

Comment: What do you mean "more recent" ? I'm using 9.2. EDIT : it works on my version

Comment: @dystroy . . . Works in 9.1 and onward, but not in 9.0 and previous.  That means that it generally will not work in most postgres-derived databases, such as Paracel, Netezza, Redshift, Vertica, and so on.

Comment: Yes but as I had tagged my question 9.2 I thought my requirement was clear.